# Barcode scanner plugin irregular behaviour in ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2, barcode-scanner

I have implemented `Barcode` scanner in ionic 2 application, It is working nicely but for sometimes it is not detecting the `Barcode` pattern and sometimes delaying in `Barcode` detection, What could be the possible reason, why there is delay in pattern detection or not detection. Please suggest.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner/

Comment: @Naveen, Barcode scanner I have implemented, my question is about its irregular behaviour, sometimes it scans and sometimes not, is there any dependency or else?

Comment: try to native bar-code reader https://github.com/ErNaveen/ZxingDemo